# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named installing package from azure devops artifacts

Tags: docker, azure-devops, pip, azure-artifacts

I'm using azure devops to upload an artifact through twine a package that is a custom library..

So far the process of uploading the artifact to azure devops is correct and it works fine.

I am using the azure feed url to download the package as follows:

I have a pip.ini file in my C:\Users\myuser\pip directory

```
pip.ini
```

```
[global]
index-url=https://mytoken@pkgs.dev.azure.com/ctsebs/DevOps/_packaging/stockv3/pypi/simple/
```

with this url from a cmd i can use

```
pip install stock_pivot_sql

...

Successfully installed stock_pivot_sql-1.4
```

Right now my package is installed correctly... but when I want to use it I get this error

```
>>> import stock_pivot_sql
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stock_pivot_sql'
```

Now if I execute another command to list the packages it gives me this result

```
C:\Users\leonarac>pip show stock-pivot-sql
Name: stock-pivot-sql
Version: 1.4
Summary: stock_pivot_sql
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email:
License:
Location: c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

i tried to replicate the same in docker by creating an image but i get the same error

```
$ docker run -t -i --rm  stockv3 bash
root@52c5ac162f5a:/# pip show stock_pivot_sql
Name: stock-pivot-sql
Version: 1.4
Summary: stock_pivot_sql
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author:
Author-email:
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
root@52c5ac162f5a:/# python
Python 3.9 (main, May 23 2023, 14:17:54) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import stock_pivot_sql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stock_pivot_sql'
```